# surface area of the part of the circular paraboloid

Tags: integration

Find the surface area of the part of the circular paraboloid[image]
that lies inside the cylinder [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this exactly the same way as your other surface area problem. Recall the surface area formula:

[image: integral]

$$f_y=2y, f_x=2x.$$

So we have $$S=\int_{-5}^5\int_{-\sqrt{25-x^2}}^{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\sqrt{(2x)^2+(2y)^2+1}dydx$$

Can you take it from there?

Alternatively, you could do this using polar coordinates, which is much easier:

$$S=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{5}\sqrt{4r^2+1}rdrd\theta$$

Comment: There is something wrong with that answer, I got 273.687 and it says that it is wrong!

Comment: Sorry, made a typo on the bounds. It's fixed now.

Comment: now I got 162.5726 and it is also wrong!

Comment: Check your work please.

Comment: I did but It keep giving me that answer, can you give me the final answer that you got!

Comment: hey i got the right answer now Thanks I really appreciate your help!